# EF 6.0 how to cancel delete and modify property?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have a Table `Table1` with column `State` which `1` means normal data and `10` means removed data,
and I want to cancel delete operation and update this column to `10` when I deleting it in EF Database First:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        switch (entry.State)
        {
            case EntityState.Deleted:
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entry.CurrentValues["State"] = 10;
                break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

and delete like this:

```
var data = dbContext.Table1.Find(primaryKey);
dbContext.Table1.Remove(data);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

before `base.SaveChanges()` I checked `State` value in `entry.Entity`, it has been changed from `1` to `10`, but after `SaveChanges`, `State` value in database didn't changed (still `1`).

how can I make this work?